# How to click on a link with page.link but without id (it has class)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

This is my code by now

```
async function main(){

  for(int=0;int<50;int++){

    const allLinks = await getLinks();
    //console.log(allLinks);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
   
    const scrapedData = [];

    for(let link of allLinks){
      const data = await getPageData(link,page);
      // const secondToWait = (Math.floor(Math.random()*5) + 1)*100; //número aleatorio entre 1000 y 4000 (entre 1 y 4 segundos)
      // await page.waitForTimeout(3000) //van a quitar 'waitfor', pero 'waitForTimeout' es parecido; waits 3 seconds before it goes to the next page (a veces que cargen tan rápido las páginas puede causar problemas)
      scrapedData.push(data);
    }
    await page.click('#next a');
  }
```

the '#next' is the class, but it doesent work 'cause i need the id. Any ways to solve that? I traed to find, but i only find answares for bottoms, and dosent work in my case.

This is the code from the page im scraping

```
<div>
    <ul class="pager">
        
        <li class="current">
        
            Page 1 of 50
        
        </li>
        
            <li class="next"><a href="catalogue/page-2.html">next</a></li>
        
    </ul>
</div>


        </div>
    </section>
```

(the page: https://books.toscrape.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#` is for ID, for class use dot `.` so it

```
await page.click('.next a');
```